# Is libdmtx dead, suggested replacement?

Tags: c++, c, windows, barcode

I've been using [libdmtx](http://www.libdmtx.org) in a project and looking to update to a newer version, but it seems the project hasn't been updated in well over a year.  The last update/version was June, 2011.  The [Git repository](http://libdmtx.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libdmtx/libdmtx;a=shortlog) shows that the last commit was August, 2011.  Finally, the author's web site, which previously promoted libdmtx, [Dragonfly Logic](http://www.dragonflylogic.com/), is dead with a 404 Not Found error.

Is there another data matrix library that can meet this criteria?

- Open source
- Platform-neutral C/C++ (i.e. can build for Windows, POSIX environments)
- Encodes/decodes data matrix
- Actively maintained

Alternatively, did libdmtx move somewhere else and continue to get maintained somewhere that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Is there a bug in the current version that makes it unsuitable for you?

Comment: Yeah, plus there is the disconcerting fact that I'm relying on something which is apparently unmaintained now.  I'd rather switch to something maintained that meets the above criteria.

Comment: seems it is time to fork it ... you could be the new maintainer :)

Comment: Maybe you should send your question to libdmtx's author; here's his google+ page: https://plus.google.com/113430642061473350520/posts

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can't say that I'll *never* develop on libdmtx again, but it certainly wouldn't be anytime soon. I simply don't have the spare hours anymore to even keep up with the correspondence, let alone to perform any meaningful development.

So if you wish to fork it, you have my blessing. :)

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any other open source packages that do exactly the same things as libdmtx (which is why I created it in the first place), but I tried to list any similar projects I came across at http://libdmtx.sourceforge.net/resources.php

Good luck!

Comment: That awkward moment when you ask a question about a library on SO and get the library author's response...

Comment: libdmtx.org seems to have been repurposed but docs still point there. The available Windows binaries require an older version of ImageMagick or they fail without message to stderr but an Error window. Only relatively recent ones available on imagemagick.org, but I found some here: http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

As libdmtx is currently unmaintained (I wouldn't say dead, as there are several users of the library) one should have to look at options.

[zxing-cpp](https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp) is a viable alternative. It can code and decode both DataMatrix, QR codes and barcodes. It compiles both on windows and posix, and are open source (Apache 2)

My only complaint about the zxing-cpp library is that is doesn't support dot peen generated data matrix images.

Answer (score 1):

This Github project has revived libdmtx in 2016 with sporadic but ongoing activity since then: https://github.com/dmtx

(I am not affiliated with this project, just wanted to add an update to this question after finding it in a search.)