# How to locate and read Data Matrix code with python

Tags: python, opencv, datamatrix

I'm trying to read a datamatrix barcodes on the bottom of microtubes. I tried [libdmtx](http://libdmtx.sourceforge.net/) which has python bindings and works reasonably well when the dots of the matrix are square but much worse when they are round as here:

[image: datamatrix sample]

Another complication is a shine which in some cases reaches the code area.

The barcodes are scanned in a rack on a flatbed scanner so they have constant size and are roughly centered. The orientation is random.

I came to a conclusion I'd have to locate the codes and improve the image myself. I use python and OpenCV 3.1. I have already tried thresholding, contours:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

well = plt.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqHkw.png')
well = cv2.cvtColor(well, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
plt.subplot(151); plt.imshow(well)

x, thr = cv2.threshold(well, .4[enter image description here][2], 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thr = np.uint8(thr)
plt.subplot(152); plt.imshow(thr)

dst, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thr.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros_like(thr), contours, -1, 255, 1)
plt.subplot(153); plt.imshow(c)

areas = map(lambda x: cv2.contourArea(cv2.convexHull(x)), contours)
max_i = areas.index(max(areas))
d = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros_like(thr), contours, max_i, 255, 1)
plt.subplot(154); plt.imshow(d)

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[max_i])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
e = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros_like(thr),[box],0,255,1)
plt.subplot(155); plt.imshow(e)

plt.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKK8j.png)

Comment: I did not even try zxing because it [reportedly does not support round elements either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017291/603323).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out that the Harris corner detector (B) finds the round elements very well with proper settings.

[image: result image here]

After thresholding (C) we detect contours of the resulting areas. We select the largest contour (D) and find a minimal bounding box (E).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import PIL
from urllib.request import urlopen

well = np.array(PIL.Image.open(urlopen('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqHkw.png')))
well = cv2.cvtColor(well, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
plt.subplot(151); plt.title('A')
plt.imshow(well)

harris = cv2.cornerHarris(well,4, 1,0.00)
plt.subplot(152); plt.title('B')
plt.imshow(harris)

x, thr = cv2.threshold(harris, 0.1 * harris.max(), 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thr = thr.astype('uint8')
plt.subplot(153); plt.title('C')
plt.imshow(thr)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thr, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(cv2.convexHull(x)) for x in contours]
max_i = areas.index(max(areas))
d = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros_like(thr), contours, max_i, 255, 1)
plt.subplot(154); plt.title('D')
plt.imshow(d)

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[max_i])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
e = cv2.drawContours(well,[box],0,1,1)
plt.subplot(155); plt.title('E')
plt.imshow(e)

plt.show()
```

Comment: appreciate that you answered it once you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3 compatibility you need to modify the above code as this:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thr.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
areas = map(lambda x: cv2.contourArea(cv2.convexHull(x)), contours)  
areas = list(areas)  
max_i = areas.index(max(areas))
```