# My code can read QR but not 2D code (datamatrix)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code, datamatrix, gs1-datamatrix

I am using the code below to decode code from an image.
This works fine with a QR code but not with a 2D datamatrix.

```
def read_qr_code(filename):
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
        value, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(img)
        return value
    except:
        print ('Error')
        return
read_qr_code('single.jpg')
```

How can I change it to decode 2D code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data matrix code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686574/how-to-read-data-matrix-code-in-python)